# juju juju bootstrap' in container uoi-bootstrap:10.0.3.147"

Tags: openstack

when i try to install open stack using this command :

```
sudo openstack-install
```

i get this error and this is my error log :

```
 [DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:21] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:21] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:22] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:22] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:22] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:23] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:23] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:23] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:24] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:24] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:24] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:25] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:25] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:25] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:26] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:26] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:26] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:27] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:27] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:27] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:28] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:28] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:28] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:29] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:29] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json in container uoi-bootstrap:-
Output: 'b'''
Stderr: 'b'cat: /run/cloud-init/result.json: No such file or directory\n''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:29] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 235)]
   Waiting for cloud-init status result
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- sudo cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, cloud_init_finished, 219)]
   {
 "v1": {
  "errors": [],
  "datasource": "DataSourceNoCloudNet [seed=/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net][dsmode=net]"
 }
}
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, create_container_and_wait, 189)]
   Container started, cloud-init done.
[INFO  • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, set_dhcp_range, 121)]
   Setting DHCP properties for host container.
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_ip, 572)]
   lxc-info found: '[b'10.0.3.147']'
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_ip, 575)]
   using 10.0.3.147 as the container ip
[INFO  • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, add_static_route, 131)]
   Adding static route for 10.0.4.0/24 via 10.0.3.147
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.single_install • (single_install.py, create_container_and_wait, 196)]
   Installing openstack & openstack-single directly, and juju-local, libvirt-bin and lxc via deps
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:10:30] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: lxc-attach -n uoi-bootstrap -- env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qy -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold install openstack openstack-single
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:12:28] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_ip, 572)]
   lxc-info found: '[b'10.0.3.147', b'10.0.4.1', b'192.168.122.1']'
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:12:28] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_ip, 575)]
   using 10.0.3.147 as the container ip
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:12:29] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_ip, 572)]
   lxc-info found: '[b'10.0.3.147', b'10.0.4.1', b'192.168.122.1']'
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:12:29] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_ip, 575)]
   using 10.0.3.147 as the container ip
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:12:29] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 610)]
   Running in container: sudo -H -u user TERM=xterm256-color ssh -t -q -l ubuntu -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa 10.0.3.147 'JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju juju bootstrap'
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:12:31] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, container_run, 623)]
   Error running command 'JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju juju bootstrap' in container uoi-bootstrap:10.0.3.147
Output: 'b'ERROR there was an issue examining the environment: admin-secret: expected string, got int(123)\r\n''
Stderr: 'b'''
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:12:31] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, global_exchandler, 62)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 77, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/single_install.py", line 303, in do_install_async
    self.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/single_install.py", line 365, in do_install
    use_ssh=True)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 627, in container_run
    subproc.returncode)
cloudinstall.utils.ContainerRunException: ("Problem running 'JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju juju bootstrap' in container uoi-bootstrap:10.0.3.147", 1)

[INFO  • 03-14 08:14:12] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 90)]
   Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[DEBUG • 03-14 08:14:12] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 96)]
Attempting to reset the terminal
```

why it try to use this IP Address :" 10.0.3.147"

how can i fix this error ?

Comment: 10.0.3.147 is your container's ip address. This error is weird though: `ERROR there was an issue examining the environment: admin-secret: expected string, got int(123)`. Can you paste your `~/.cloud-install/commands.log AND ~/.cloud-install/config.yaml`, use paste.ubuntu.com or some other pastebin

Comment: root@OS3:~# cat /home/maziar/.cloud-install/config.yaml
container_ip: 172.16.141.128
current_state: 0
install_type: Single
openstack_password: '1'
openstack_release: juno

Comment: @gangstaluv i show you `~/.cloud-install/commands.log` in my post

Comment: maybe try a different openstack password something other than a number, i filed a bug to get it fixed https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/475